# Deploying Extensible Service Proxy on custom port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to Deploy the Google Cloud Endpoint Extensible Service Proxy on a compute instance. Our compute instance is already running a web server on port 80 so I want to deploy the proxy on a custom port. I am following this guide for deploying the Extensible Service Proxy on a compute instance: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine. Also is it possible to use the Extensible Service Proxy as a reverse proxy for websites.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extensible Service Proxy is a NGINX-based proxy, you may change /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to listen in a custom port other than 80.

For example, change the line:

```
listen 80;
```

to

```
listen 8080;
```

in nginx.conf will let Extensible Service Proxy listen on port 8080.

It is also possible to use the Extensible Service Proxy as a regular reverse proxy for website, add a regular NGINX configuration to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf should work.